# How to extract data from one CSV file to another one using index value

Tags: csv, indexing, extract

I have to filter the data, therefore I need to create new CSV file based on the filters.

I am having a trouble doing it, cause the new file does not change after I run the code

Below is my code. Where I have two csv file. Stage_3_try.csv file is the one I am trying to add new data. I used enumerate to get the index value of the specific value I searched in previous csv file.

```
# Projec
import csv
from csv import writer
A = np.array([ 316143.8829, 6188926.04])
B = np.array([ 314288.7418, 6190277.519])


for i in range(0,len(east_3)):
  P = []
  P.append(east_3[i])
  P.append( north_3[i])
  P = np.asarray(P)
  projected = point_on_line(P)  #a code to do the projection 

  x_values = [A[0], B[0]]
  y_values = [A[1], B[1]]


  plt.plot(x_values, y_values, 'b-')
  if projected[0]>315745.75 and projected[1]>6188289:
    with open('Stage_3_try.csv', 'a') as f_out:
      writer = csv.writer(f_out)
      for num, row in enumerate(stage_3['UTM North NAD83']):
        if row == P[1]:
          writer.writerow(stage_3.loc[[num][0]])
          print(type(stage_3.loc[[num][0]])) 
      
    plt.plot(projected[0], projected[1], 'rx')
  f_out.close()
else:
    pass

PS: I updated the code, since the previous one worked, but when I added it to the loop, it stopped working
```

Comment: 1) Define '... new file stays intact ...' 2) Looks like `stage_3` is not a CSV file but a Pandas  data frame. Is that correct?

Comment: 1. There is not change after running the code 2. Yes, I used pandas to open the file

Comment: `open('Stage_3_try.csv', 'w')` is going to truncate any file it opens before writing. Are you looking for `open('Stage_3_try.csv', 'a')`? See [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open).

Comment: I changed it to a, and added into loop. (if you can see, I updated the code since the previous version kind of worked) however, after adding into the loop, it does not work at all

Comment: 1) You don't need `f_out.close()` as `with open('Stage_3_try.csv', 'a') as f_out` is a context manager that will automatically close the file. 2) You still are not actually defining what does not work means? Provide example expected output and actual output.

Comment: 1. Thank you so much, I did not know that 2. stage_3_try.csv is empty file. When I run the code, there is no change, and the file is still empty. Therefore, I would like to know what is wrong with the code that does not append any rows to the file. The output I am trying to get is rows with values that falls in the defined criteria. I checked separately, without appending anything to the csv file, the 'filtering' actually works and provide 'filtered' data, but writer.writerow(stage_3.loc[[num][0]]) is not working, since I get empty file.

Comment: Again you are not showing actual data. This question will not get a solution until you do. To start what are the values for `stage_3.loc[[num][0]]`?

Comment: the values of stage_3.loc[[num][0]] is pandas series and change in the range of [6188289, 6189000]. it shows the location of the data in NAD83.

Comment: 1) Python `csv` has no idea what a Pandas `series` is. You will need to provide it a `list` of values. My guess is your full code is either hiding the exception that is thrown or you are ignoring the message(s) 2) Why use Pandas for this and not just use `csv` to read the other file?

Comment: I added the full code. 1. There are over 40 columns in the data and I used projection of point on line since I need to eliminarte the points that does not fall on the criteria. 2. will it be still possible if I do the projection using csv file. like if I open the csv file as I opened the stage_3_try, is it going to be possible runs the code for projection? (sorry if my question is weird, I am still learning)

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. After you said that csv file has no idea what a Pandas series, I fixed the code using df.to_csv('Stage_3_try.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False). I really appreciate your help! Good Luck!